# Configuring webcam resolution/FPS

Tags: webcam

Just got a [Genius eMessenger 310 webcam](http://www.geniusnet.com/wSite/ct?xItem=16746&ctNode=159&mp=1), and I'm trying to change the capture resolution and FPS. The box says "Video resolution: CIF: up to 30fps, VGA: up to 30fps" but so far I've been unable to set anything other than 160x120 and what looks like 10fps.

I've tried Skype and [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/), this is the config dialog that shows up for both:

[image]

VGA SnapSize is grayed out but it refers to snapshots anyway. So no mention of resolution or FPS.

Has anyone been able to change these parameters or is this a scam and I'm just wasting my time?

Answer (score 1):

Low Light mode may result in restrictions on whether you can set these parameters.  A camera in low light may reduce the frame rate and resolution in an attempt to capture more light.  Try unchecking the Low Light setting.

While I am not familiar with webcams, this is my experience with a variety of camera devices.

Answer (score 0):

Try reducing the Exposure to 64 or less. This will make the FPS rise up to nearly 30. And then rise the Brtightness or Gamma a little to compensate for brightness.
Source: my experience with this webcam.